# insert document into mongodb array using mongoose, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to insert a record into an mongoDB.
DB Model is as:

```
var stockhistory = new Schema({
symbol:   String,
values:   [{
    date:     Date,
    open:     Number,
    close:    Number,
    high:     Number,
    low:      Number,
    adjClose:Number,
    volume:   Number
    }]
});
```

I want to insert new document to values array.

I have tried the following but getting error.

```
var insertObj = {
    'date': obj[0].lt,
    'open': obj[0].op,
    'close': obj[0].l,
    'high': obj[0].hi,
    'low': obj[0].lo,
    'adjClose': obj[0].l_fix,
     'volume': obj[0].vo
 };
var sname = 'symbol';
var History = require('../model/stockHistory');
var history = new History({ symbol: sname, values: insertObj });
history.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    } else {
        console.log("Quote saved");
    }
});
```

And

```
History.findOneAndUpdate(
                                {symbol: sname},
                                {$push: {values: insertObj}},
                                {safe: true, upsert: true},
                                function(err, model) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
```

I am not sure about the document insert into array and tried above after searching on google but not getting through.

Thanks for help !

Edit

Records are successfully created now but new records are created as a document but not under values array.Please have a look at screenshot(link given below)

I want to create new record in values so that count after creation will be 2696 instead it created new separate document.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0HTX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your schema, `values` is an array, but when you do:

`var history = new History({ symbol: sname, values: insertObj });`

You are setting values as an object. You could try:

```
var insertObj = {
    'date': obj[0].lt,
    'open': obj[0].op,
    'close': obj[0].l,
    'high': obj[0].hi,
    'low': obj[0].lo,
    'adjClose': obj[0].l_fix,
     'volume': obj[0].vo
   };
var sname = 'symbol';
var History = require('../model/stockHistory');
var history = new History({ symbol: sname, values: insertArr });
History.findOneAndUpdate(
   {symbol: sname},
   {$push: {values: insertObj}},
   {safe: true, upsert: true},
   function(err, model) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried the solution that you provided but record did not get inserted.

Comment: Record created now with mine as well as your solution.Error was because of typecasting of DATE field.But the problem is that new records are getting created as a seperate document but not in array.I am updating my Q with screenshot.Please have a look there.

Comment: When does this happen? this will happen when you use the save method, as you are instantiating a new history. If you just want to insert the object to an existing document then you just run the findOneAndUpdate with upsert true

Comment: second option using findOneAndUpdate has worked for me now.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice! I'll add this to my answers, can you please accept it?

Comment: Yeah sure,Just 1 edit, Array is not required in my case.insertObj will work as array will create array inside array .Both cases will work depends on the requirement.

Comment: every time I am inserting a record, id field is automatically generating
But I don't want id field in my array.Any idea on that?

Comment: I've edited my answer so it doesnt use the save method

Comment: I think it'd be better to create another question with the code as it is now so things won't start to be confusing